# Why ng-bind doesn't work with AngularStrap for me?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angular-strap, ng-bind

I need your help with AngularStrap tabs and displaying calculated data. So, let's say I have a few inputs with ng-model. I calculate them and display in ng-bind. Everything works fine until I use tabs from AngularStrap. Then my output goes NaN - it looks like ng-model doesn't update, when I'm changing it's content.
You can take a look at what I mean here:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div bs-active-pane="tabs.activeTab" bs-tabs>
            <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" data-title="{{ tab.title }}" name="{{ tab.title }}" disabled="{{ tab.disabled }}" ng-include="tab.templateUrl" bs-pane>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.multiply = function(){
    return $scope.first * $scope.second;
};
$scope.add = function(){
    return $scope.first + $scope.second;
};
$scope.tabs = [
{
    "title": "First",
    "templateUrl": "first.html"
},
{
    "title": "Second",
    "templateUrl": "second.html"
}];
$scope.tabs.activeTab = "First";
}]);
```

*first.html*

```
<input type="number" ng-model="first">
        <input type="number" ng-model="second">
        {{first}}
        {{second}}
        {{multiply()}}
```

*second.html*

```
<input type="number" ng-model="first">
        <input type="number" ng-model="second">
        {{first}}
        {{second}}
        {{add()}}
```

What is really weird, is that when I use it without the tabs, it's working perfectly. Where is the mistake? How can I make it work with tabs?

*This example is working like a charm:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="number" ng-model="first">
        <input type="number" ng-model="second">
        {{first}}
        {{second}}
        {{multiply()}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```